# Opening a URL in background through Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am using **Application.OpenURL** , for opening a url, it works fine.
But the problem is it will also bring the browser application to the front.
I just want to open the url in background..
Is there any way to do this.
Thanx for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use **Application.OpenURL** it will open the browser on the foreground and there isn't much that you can do about it.

If you just want to get the content of an URL you can use the [WWW](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/WWW.html) class. This will let you get the content but will not open it in the browser.